# ERROR in [at-loader] TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'twitter-text'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, gulp

I am seeing this error message:
`ERROR in [at-loader] TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'twitter-text'.`

I had some serious issues with Webpack Sass compilation time (4 - 5 minutes[!sic]) so my Angular project now uses Webpack for TypeScript and Gulp for Sass compilation.
The `ERROR in [at-loader] TS2688` part of the error message means it's coming from TypeScript. Nowhere in my app I use anything that would have a 'twitter-text' in it - that's why the error is so baffling. Scouring the internets didn't help. There simply is no information when you paste this error into almight google bar.